# Python 3 STDOUT Processing

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have searched high and low for an example of how to process the STDOUT of a subprocess, but with no luck.

I have a test command line executable that produces output continually and am trying to read the STDOUT in real-time and print this to the screen. Eventually it will process the data locally and then send a summary onto another machine, but I have simplified this down to ask this question.

I have tried to use Python to do this as shown in the code below:

```
import subprocess, time, os, sys
cmd = [sys.executable, 'TestStdOut.exe']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(">>> " + line)
```

The test executable I am using just outputs dateTime for the moment, and the stdout looks like this:

```
....
16/11/2015 10:52:44
16/11/2015 10:52:44
16/11/2015 10:52:44
16/11/2015 10:52:44
16/11/2015 10:52:44
16/11/2015 10:52:45
....
```

But I am getting this error and I cannot work out why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_stdout.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(">>> " + line)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

I was expecting the Python to simply display the same lines as if I ran the executable from the command line. I have googled the error, but I cannot seem to find an answer.

What am I missing?

Many thanks

Pete

UPDATE : Thanks to 2RING I went back and reviewed my notes, this code now works:

```
import subprocess, time, os, sys
cmd = ['TestStdOut.exe']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)


while True:
  line = p.stdout.readline()
  if line != '':
    print(line.rstrip().decode('utf-8'))
  else:
    break
```

Comment: What happens if you do `print(">>> ", line)`?

Comment: Hi, I changed the + to a , and I now get this error:python test_stdout.py
>>>  b'  File "TestStdOut.exe", line 1\r\n'
>>>  b"SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\\x90' in file TestStdOut.exe
on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ fo
r details\r\n"

Comment: It sounds like your `TestStdOut.exe` is printing non-ASCII bytes. So you need to decode those bytes to Unicode, and then `print` will encode them to (what it believes is) the default encoding for your terminal. If you don't know what encoding `TestStdOut.exe` is using try `'latin1'`, eg `print(line.decode('latin1'))`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it now throws -> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing, I am guessing I have something missing at the end of the for loop . Sorry for my ignorance, I have only been learning Python for a few days!

Comment: Ah, ok. :) In that case, maybe you should play with some simpler language features for a while first; using `subprocess` isn't hard, but it can be a bit confusing when you're not familiar with Python. But anyway... If `TestStdOut.exe` is a normal binary executable then you don't want `sys.executable` in your `cmd` list. `sys.executable` is the full absolute path of the Python interpreter (or it can be an empty string or `None` if Python can't find the absolute path on your OS). You'd only use `sys.executable` in the `cmd` list if `TestStdOut.exe` is a Python script.

Comment: Thanks, will take another look at the manuals!